# Shiny for Python Plotly Choropleth Map Animation Frame Rendering

Tags: python, plotly-python, shiny-reactivity, choropleth, py-shiny

I am currently using Shiny for Python and am attempting to render a Plotly Express [choropleth map](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.choropleth). I am using the `animation_frame` parameter for the years in my dataset, so in the animation you can view the map across the years. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-an-animated-choropleth-map-with-less-than-15-lines-of-code-2ff04921c60b) is a nice example of what an animated choropleth map looks like.

The code that I've written for the map renders properly and the animation works when I run it using Jupyter Notebooks, but when I click the play button on the same map using Shiny the animation does not render.

Has anyone ever had this problem, and how did you solve it? My guess is that I'm missing a specific decorator function, but I'm unsure which one. I'm a beginner with Shiny, so any help will be greatly appreciated. I think a major issue might be that there is no `ui.input` associated with the widget and so Shiny doesn't expect itself to change. I had run the `App` using `debug=True`, and there was nothing logged when I clicked the play animation button on the choropleth map.

This is essentially what my code looks like:

```py
from shiny import ui, App, reactive
from shinywidgets import output_widget, render_widget
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

graph = ..... ## excluded the code here, graph works on Jupyter Notebooks 

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    output_widget("choro_graph")
)

def server(input, output, session):
    @output
    @render_widget
    def choro_graph():
        return graph

app = App(app_ui, server)
```